# Caption and fonts size issues with tabularx

Tags: captions, fontsize, tabularx

This table works OK. However,

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllX}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D\\
    \midrule

    A & B & C & aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa \\
    \hline

\end{tabularx}
```

when I change the font size, as in the next table,

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllX}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D\\
    \midrule
    \footnosize
    A & B & C & aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

I get the error message:

```
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}.
```

Also, I cannot add a caption; if I do,

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllX}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D\\
    \midrule
    \caption{ABC}
    A & B & C & aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

I get a list of error messages:

```
! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
\caption@hrule ->\hrule 
                        \@height \z@ 
l.167 \end{tabularx}

To put a horizontal rule in an hbox or an alignment,
you should use \leaders or \hrulefill (see The TeXbook).

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.167 \end{tabularx}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.167 \end{tabularx}
...
```

I have worked around the title issue by adding the line
`\captionof{table}{\textbf{Inflation categories}}` before `\begin{tabularx}`, but the downside is that the title and table can end up in different pages.

How can I solve this issues?

**EDIT 1**
After the messages below, this is a working solution:

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{ABC}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllX}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D\\
    \midrule

    A & B & C & aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

I had a typo in `\footnotesize` and `tabularx` needs to be encapsulated by `table`.

Comment: If you wrote ``\footnotesize` instead of \foonosize? For the caption, it has to be inside of a `table`environment, like this: `\begin{table}\caption{ABC}\label{some label}\begin{tabularx}{lllX} ..... \end{tabularx} \end{table}`.

Comment: `Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}.` is not the format of a tex error message. the tex error would show you which command is undefined. (look in the log file)

Comment: do you use texstudio?

Comment: @Bernard Your comments solved the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using Textstudio, next time will consider the log file.

Comment: please consider leaving a comment here https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/ I know nothing about texstudio but it is so depressing that I can recognise its use, just by user confusion over undefined commands. They really could fix this.

Answer (score 3):

When I compile the following document,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllX}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D\\
    \midrule
    \footnosize
    A & B & C & aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \footnosize 

l.11 \end{tabularx}
```

Thus, it is `\footnosize`, not `\end{tabularx}`, that's the subject of the complaint. What to do? Just in case it's not painfully obvious: change `\footnosize` to `\footnotesize`.

I assume you're aware that the `\footnotesize` directive doesn't affect the entire row, but only the first cell of the row in question.

To apply a `\caption` to this table, it's necessary to embed the `tabularx` environment in a `table` environment, something like this:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Stuff} \label{tab:stuff}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllX}
...
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```